# preg_replace is processing a function as a property

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to create a template system for a web site I am working on. I am trying to use preg_replace to call a function to process data that is surrounded by certain tags. For example, process('date') would return today's date, and is put in the code as $*date*$. I am using preg_replace to find the strings I need to modify, but I can not call the function - PHP seems to think that the function is a property instead.

This is the code I am using:

```
$view = preg_replace("/\$_([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)_\$/e", "$this->process('\\1')", $view);
```

This is the error I get:

*Notice: Undefined property: ClassName::$process in /location/ClassName.class.php on line X*

I hope I explained this sufficiently. How do I get preg_replace to execute process as a method, instead of trying to display it as a property?

Comment: is `$this` in the correct scope when it replaces the string?

Comment: I believe so... I can add a line echo $this->process('date'); above the preg_replace and that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead of preg_replace seeing as preg_replace_callback is designed for what you are actually trying to do. A possible issue you could be having is scope/function accessibility. If your code that is calling preg_replace doesn't have access to the function you are trying to call, then you could be getting this error since PHP can't find the function and might be defaulting to treating it as an parameter. If the function isn't in the same file as this preg_replace, try putting it there to see if it changes anything.

Comment: The function is a method in the same class as the method that is calling preg_replace. I was considering using preg_replace_callback, but I wasn't sure that scope would be maintained properly. Would I be calling it as: preg_replace_callback("/\$_([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)_\$/", "this->process", $view); or how would I indicate the scope of process?

Comment: After testing it, preg_replace_callback that is either called on a member function of the class or passed a class variable will not work at all. Basically, anything using $this in preg_replace_callback throws an error, so that has me back to trying to get preg_replace to work.

Comment: Try changing your called method to a static method. I have seen this before and deals with the fact that the template object is calling code after compile time that coded as an object but is not getting created as an object when the code is called.